# Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0

Tags: android, react-native

this is driving me crazy for days.

I can't run my app on an android emulator: when I run `react-native run-android` I get the following error:

```
> Task :react-native-maps:compileDebugRenderscript FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-maps:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0.
  Required by:
      project :react-native-maps
   > Cannot find a version of 'com.android.support:support-compat' that satisfies the version constraints: 
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:loader:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:customview:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:viewpager:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:drawerlayout:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
        Constraint path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
        Constraint path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0
        Constraint path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat' strictly '26.1.0' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 26.1.0



 // etc. 
// many com.android.support:XXX couldn't be resolved.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
10 actionable tasks: 10 executed
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:602:13)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:622:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

As you can see, I did add `maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}` to my project `build.gradle` but it did not solve the issue.

Here is my project's `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

my `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.thetkmapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

and my react-native-maps `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
      // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
      url "$rootDir/node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've been trying anything I find online, but nothing worked for me so far. 
What can I do

Comment: Try to add this `implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"` and run again.

Comment: Hi @FaysalAhmed, thank you very much for your help. I just tried to add this to my `app/build.gradle` but the build failed again with the same error.

Comment: Please also added this `implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"` and try again.

Comment: It failed again with the exact same error :(

Comment: Have your dependency synced properly?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the sync fails with the above mentioned error

Comment: it is disabled as expected :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188587/discussion-between-faysal-ahmed-and-jules-corb).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution !

change in `build.gradle`:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
```

to

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check in your error log, it says that React 58 uses support-compat:28.0.0 and the Maps module uses support-compat:26.1.0. I believe Gradle is not smart enough to resolve that.

From your logs, it says:

```
Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.4' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
```

And then:

```
Dependency path 'theTKMapp:react-native-maps:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1' --> 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0' --> 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
```

The react-native-maps is using the latest version of the Play-services-base available at the moment but that still uses support-v4:26.1.0. We don't have any version of the play-services-base available using version 28 of the support library.

You can try to exclude the support library from the play-services dependencies in the maps module.
**REPLACE** THEM by this. 
FILE: node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build.gradle:  (you may have to fork this project)

```
  implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$googlePlayServicesVersion") { dep ->
    dep.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
  }
  implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$googlePlayServicesMapsVersion") { dep ->
    dep.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
  }
```

OR, you can add this to your android block inside maps.

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was fixed by refering the following [link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2695#issuecomment-472929257) i am just pasting the solution here below from the link.

---

This issue has been fixed for me also by adding this line into the react-native-maps 's build.gradle file

important : what I didn't catch immediately is that this line should be added directly in the node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  def googlePlayServicesVersion = safeExtGet('googlePlayServicesVersion', DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION)
  // Variable lookup order : googlePlayServicesMapsVersion > googlePlayServicesVersion > DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_MAPS_VERSION
  def googlePlayServicesMapsVersion = safeExtGet('googlePlayServicesMapsVersion', safeExtGet('googlePlayServicesVersion', DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_MAPS_VERSION))
  def androidMapsUtilsVersion = safeExtGet('androidMapsUtilsVersion', DEFAULT_ANDROID_MAPS_UTILS_VERSION)

  compileOnly "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$googlePlayServicesMapsVersion"
  implementation "com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:$androidMapsUtilsVersion"

  // ⬇️This line made Gradle sync successfully
  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears there is mixing of versions which causes crushing.
could you please try to adjust for 26 versions as 
**compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'** or compile to the latest

Kindly do something like Invalidate and Restart as well then Build once again.

Comment: Hi ntonsite mwamlima, thank you for your help; I just added this line to my dependencies in my `app/build.gradle` file, but it failed to build again, with the same error unfortunately.

Comment: still running the same issue after I did 'invalidate and restart' :(

Answer (score 0):

change classpath to latest classpath
and add this line to gradle

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Hi @Athira, thank you very much for your help ! How do I get the latest classpath ? also, should I add `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` into my project's `build.gradle` or in my `android/app/build.gradle` file ?

Comment: in replace old appcompact to this one android/app/build.gradle file

Comment: Latest version is 3.3.1

Comment: Unfortunately, it failed again :'(

Comment: change react-native-maps build.gradle class path

Comment: change buildToolsVersion '28.0.3' to buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'

Comment: add this line too, last try :) implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

That was my solution, changing the buildgrade to code below:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}